# Apache doesn't parse PHP on VHOST while it works on default

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, lamp, virtualhost

I set up a Debian 6 VPS to host couple of small sites and it works beautifully for default one.

Next i created new user and copy/paste default vhost file and enabled it with *a2ensite* and only adjusted paths accordingly for that new user but for some reason PHP files aren't parsed and only their source is displayed.

So, recap: identical vhost settings, PHP module enabled, short tags on (but not used)

To make it clear: I search and found bunch of "solutions" here and on the web elsewhere but none of those seemed to work for me.

Just noticed this string in logs :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/tester/public_html/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

[Thu Mar 21 20:28:55 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/tester/public_html/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/user/public_html:/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

*And this is my default vhost file content:*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin user@mail.com
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/
        ErrorLog /home/user/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/user/logs/access.log combined

        <Directory "/home/user/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
                php_admin_flag engine on
                php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/user/public_html:/tmp"
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Could PHP's **open_basedir** be the culprit of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! Got it working!

Checked Apache's PHP module conf settings at /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml|ps)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
#
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

**It clearly says:**

```
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.)
```

So I did, then restarted Apache and voila:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be7dj.png]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, open_basedir can be root of this problem. You must have /home/tester/public_html/ in path and you have /home/user.

Looks like it skip PHP parsing and not block access to page as I tough - I found similar problem solved here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=57877 .

/First version with asking for clarification deleted as not complying with ServerFault policies as I was told./

Comment: Yeah, PHP is enabled that way and it works on default vhost. All files are having .php extension. Totally confusing..

Comment: @purpler Yes, you answer yourself I think (see link in my edited answer).

Comment: Nah, default PHP module config was the real culprit. I Explained below. Thanks for help tho!